# Iterator worked properly for vector . How? Why?

Tags: collections

whenever we read difference between any arraylist and vector. It's said we use iterator for arraylist and enumerator for vector. i used iterator for vector. it worked properly.How? Is it newly added feature ?

Comment: I can find no such claims, and found articles such as this: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/vector/vector-iterator-example/

Comment: This made me remember my old physics classes, when we see that a vector has a module and a direction... what a direction to put a vector... and what a change in the module this could be... nice and clean... easy, soft... waw... very nice... congrats ^^